# how to edit the record in another pageblocktable of the the same vf page using custom controller

Tags: page-layout, pageblocktable, pageblocksection

**[image: strong text]**

my problem is ...after saving,the record is not getting in Pageblock 2.how to get the record automatically after save the record

```
<apex:page Controller="siteportal" showHeader="false" id="pageId"> 
   <apex:form id="formid">
        <apex:pageBlock id="pb1" > 
            <apex:pageBlockButtons > 
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages> 
                <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!emp1.Name}" required="false"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>  
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock id="abc">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!emp}" var="acc"  >             
            <apex:column headerValue="Action" >       
            <apex:outputLink value="/apex/siteportalvf?id={!acc.id}" >Edit</apex:outputLink>
            <apex:param name="param" assignTo="{!acc.id}" value="param"/>
            &nbsp;|&nbsp;
            <a href="javascript:if (window.confirm('Are you sure?')) DeleteAccount('{!acc.Id}');" style="font-weight:bold" >Del</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;      
            <apex:commandLink action="{!saveEdit}">Save </apex:commandLink> 
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="account name">
            <apex:outputfield value="{!acc.name}"  >
            <apex:inlineEditSupport event="onclick" />  
            </apex:outputfield>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="phone">
            <apex:outputfield value="{!acc.phone}"  >
            <apex:inlineEditSupport event="onclick" /> 
            </apex:outputfield>
            </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!DeleteAccount}" name="DeleteAccount" reRender="form" >
   <apex:param name="accountid" value="" assignTo="{!SelectedAccountId}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>


        <apex:pageblock id="block3">   
            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!acclist1}" var="acc">
            <apex:column headerValue="Account Name">
            <apex:inputText value="{!acc.Name}"></apex:inputText>
            </apex:column>
             <apex:column headerValue="Account Phone">
            <apex:inputText value="{!acc.Phone}"></apex:inputText>
            </apex:column>

           <apex:column >
            <apex:commandButton value="Update" action="{!UpdateAcc}" reRender="pageId,abc,pb1"/>

            </apex:column>
              <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
            </apex:pageblockTable>
        </apex:pageblock>
        </apex:form>
        </apex:page>
```

## controller

```
public class siteportal { 
     public boolean DisplayContacts{get;set;}
    public string Employeename          {set;get;}
     public string SelectedAccountId {get; set;}
    public string save                          {set;get;}
    public List<Account> emp    {get;set;}
     public Account emp2        {get;set;}
    public Account emp1 {get;set;}
    public boolean showemp{get;set;}
    public List<Account> accList {get;set;}
    public List<Account> accList1 {get;set;}
      public Account editContact { get; set; }
  public Boolean rendered{set;get;}
  public string accID{get;set;}

    public siteportal() {
    setupAccount();
    emp1=new Account();
    emp = [Select id,name,phone from Account where createddate=today]; 
    showemp=true;

    accID=apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('accID'); 
    accList1 = [Select id,Name,Phone from Account where ID =: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') ];

    } 
    public void setupAccount(){
        accList = [Select name, id from Account ]; 
            }

     public void save(){
       upsert emp1; 

     ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'Record Created Successfully.Thank you!'));
    }

    public void UpdateAcc(){
      update accList1;
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'Record Updated Successfully.Thank you!'));
    }
     public void DeleteAccount(){
      Account del = new Account(ID=SelectedAccountId);
      delete del; 
    setupAccount();
   }    
    public String getParam(String name) {
        return ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(name);   
    }
    public PageReference add() {      
           DisplayContacts=true; 
           return null;
       }


    public PageReference saveEdit() {
            UPDATE Emp;
       return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refersh the `emp` list as well.

```
public void UpdateAcc(){
      update accList1;
      emp = [Select id,name,phone from Account where createddate=today]; 
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'Record Updated Successfully.Thank you!'));
    }
```

But as you are updating record instead of creating . So this query might not give you updated result. so you can try something like.

```
public void UpdateAcc(){
      update accList1;
      emp = [Select id,name,phone from Account where Lastmodifieddate = today]; 
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'Record Updated Successfully.Thank you!'));
    }
```